# Display sibling <i> on click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to display the hidden `<i>` when I click on the first. I've tried to read about this and tried different variations of `siblings()` etc, but I can't get it to work. Can someone please explain what I should do?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="locationactions">
  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-check" style="display: none;"></i>
</div>
```

```js
$('.adminapp .locationactions i').click(function() {
  if (currentApp != "adminapp") 
    return;

  $(this).closest('i').show(150);
});
```

Comment: Try with `$(this).next('i')` assuming that you want `<i class="fas fa-check" style="display: none;"></i>` to be visible

Comment: I recommend not using `.next(selector)` as it can be confusing if the selector isn't the next sibling.  Instead use `.nextAll("i").first()` to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` looks for the nearest *parent* element, whereas the `i` you want to target is a sibling. As such, use `siblings('i')` or `next('i')`:

```js
var currentApp = 'adminapp';

$('.adminapp .locationactions i').click(function() {
  if (currentApp != "adminapp")
    return;

  $(this).next('i').show(150); // looks at the following sibling element ONLY
  // Alternative:
  // $(this).siblings('i').show(150); // looks at ALL siblings
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adminapp">
  <div class="locationactions">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt">fa-trash-alt</i>
    <i class="fas fa-check" style="display: none;">fa-check</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad to help